# Maven, switching to a different profile

Tags: maven, profile, pom.xml, activation

I have a problem with proper maven profile configuration of a project that is deployed to a continuous integration server.

In my project, there are some resources that needs to be included only during tests at the daily building phase and others that needs to be included during nightly builds, and they can never be included both at the same time, because building process will fail, I can achive this locally by activating one profile at the same time.

Continuous integration server runs following maven commands:
-during daily builds:

```
mvn clean package -Pci -Dci
```

-during nightly builds

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore -Pci,nightly -Dci -Dnightly
```

As you see, nightly build command include maven variables and profiles defined in daily build command, which makes some troubles for me, becouse I want to have only one profile activated at the same time.

Specifically, what I want is having 3 separate profiles:
-my-pforile (activated by default, not used on CI server)
-ci-profile (activated only on daily builds, used on CI server)
-nightly-profile (activated only on nightly builds, used on CI server)

How can I achieve that? I tried almost everything. Reconfiguring CI server is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

When I have to configure the same build with different profiles, using Jenkins as a CI, 
I usually create as much builds as profiles, so each build uses the correct configuration.

If adding a new build is not an option probably you can try to create a workaround
using something like the exec plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to download 
the resources from a ftp (or something else). 
You will have also to create a cron job (or equivalent) to replace the correct resources between the builds: 
in the evening you put there the resources for the night, in the morning the ones for the day.

But considering how cumbersome this process will be, probably it is better to try to add 
a new build.

Comment: +1 for the note about different builds for different profiles.  Important for integration testing as well.